# Linearlayout sobre uma listview

Tags: android, android-layout

Tenho um LinearLayout que quero que quando ele ficar VISIBLE ele sobreponha uma listview, como fazer isso? 
Quero que meu LinearLayout opcaoOrdenar sobreponha a listview quando ele for setado como VISIBLE.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">


<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/opcaoOrdenar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/linearLayout"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:weightSum="1"
    android:visibility="gone">

    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/radioGroupData"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.36"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        >

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/maiorData"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:text="Maior data" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/menorData"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/questao"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/sim"
            android:text="Menor data" />

    </RadioGroup>

    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/radioGroupResultado"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true">

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/melhorResultado"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/questao"

            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/sim"
            android:text="Melhor resultado" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/piorResultado"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/questao"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/sim"
            android:text="Pior resultado" />

    </RadioGroup>


</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:background="@color/cinza">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/ordenaramc"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:background="@color/azulgerdau"
        android:text="Ordenar"
        android:textColor="@color/cinza" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buscarAmc"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:background="@color/azulgerdau"
        android:onClick="buscarAmc"
        android:text="Buscar"
        android:textColor="@color/cinza" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/adicionarAmc"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:background="@color/azulgerdau"
        android:onClick="adicionarAmc"
        android:text="Adicionar"
        android:textColor="@color/cinza" />

</LinearLayout>

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listaAmc"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_above="@+id/linearLayout"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"></ListView>
```

Comment: Você pode colocar a visibilidade da sua`ListView` para `View.GONE`, enquanto seu layout para `VISIBLE`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Só definir ele por último dentro do RelativeLayout, ou seja, move pro final do código. No RelativeLayout ou FrameLayout as view vão sendo "empilhadas" conforme a ordem em que são definidas, ou seja, a última é a que fica mais em cima.